# Do I need different Authentication Token for each user for sending message using C2DM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I know there is unique registartionId get from users email address for sending message to his device, but also do i need to have different authenctication id for each user?

If I am right we just need registrationId to send message to user, where as AuthenticationId is static, which is use to send message to user with registration id.

but in my case, I got Authentication Token using my developer email address, and if send message to the same email address I receive message. and If I send message to another user using registration id received from his email address and using authentication token got from my developer account email address user didn't receive message.

and again if I use authentication token got from user's email address and password and using his registration id user receive message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *authenticationToken* confirms that you have a valid Google account and thus are in general allowed to send C2DM messages. The *registrationToken* is directly tied to a user's device **and** your application. It allows your application to use your *authenticationToken* to send a message to the user's device.

You need **one** *authenticationToken* to send messages to **all** devices for which you have *registrationTokens*. Note however, that you should pick up a new authenticationToken **every time** you start sending messages, as those can be changed by Google at random.

I recall reading that Google advises to use different mail accounts for sending and receiving.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the Authentication token is generated against the c2dm gmail id and the gmail account configured on the device.

That may be the reason why the other user is not receiving messages using your registration id.

So the answer to your question is yes, you need to have different Authentication Token for different user for sending message using C2DM.

Comment: That's not right, the authentication id is the id of the gmail account  your server component uses to send a message to c2dm. That server is the third party application server as described here: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/android/c2dm/index.html#arch

Comment: I meant the registration id. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the authentication token is static, it serves to authenticate the app to the C2DM service. The registration id serves to identify the user you are sending the message to.

Since you are using your developer email account, it might be that the authentication token is invalidated. Did you check that? You'd get a 401 error sending the message. You shouldn't be using or collecting authentication tokens from your users, that shouldn't even work.

Note that C2DM assumes you are using a server component for your app as described here: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/android/c2dm/index.html#arch.

If you are trying to send a message to the C2DM server from the device, you're doing it wrong.